# How to Mark a Bitbucket Pullrequest

Tags: java, git, pull-request, bitbucket-server

We have 2 bitbucket plugin hooks which get triggered during the pull request merging (Plugin A --> POST receive, Plugin B --> PRE receive). 
Plugin A creates few more pull requests to down merge the code to other branches.
Plugin B makes some validation on the pull requests.

So, I don't want any validation done (by plugin B) on the pull requests created by plugin A.

Is there any way to identify the pull requests created by Plugin A?
Using Bitbucket server 4.14.5